# outer query column in inner query case expression

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vertica

I am trying to write below query in vertica

```
`SELECT a.* 
FROM   a 
WHERE  a.country="India" 
AND    a.language ="Hindi" 
AND   ( CASE WHEN (a.spoken = true 
             AND exist ( select 1 
                         FROM   b 
                         WHERE  b.country=a.country 
                          AND    b.language=a.language 
                          AND   ( CASE WHEN (a.population <b.population
                                    AND    a.statsyear > b.statsyear)) 
                                      THEN true //pick recent stats
                                    WHEN (a.population > b.population) 
                                      THEN true 
                                          ELSE false 
                                   END)) THEN true 
                     WHEN (a.written = true ) THEN
                       true   
                     ELSE false 
              END)`
```

it is not working, because we can't reference "a.population" outer query field in case expression of innerquery. I tried rewriting it wil OR caluse Vertica is not allowing it.

How can I re-write this

I created below tables in MySQL local box

```
 Example of Tables and Results
    CREATE TABLE tableA
(
   id          INT,
   country     VARCHAR(20),
   language    VARCHAR(20),
   spoken      INT,
   written     INT,
   population  INT,
   stats       INT
)
insert into tableA values(1,'India','Hindi',1,0,9,2010)
insert into tableA values(2,'India','Hindi',1,0,11,2011)
insert into tableA values(3,'India','Hindi',1,0,10,2012)
insert into tableA values(4,'India','Hindi',0,1,10,2013)
insert into tableA values(5,'India','Hindi',1,1,10,2012)
insert into tableA values(6,'India','English',1,1,10,2012)
CREATE TABLE tableB
(
   id          INT,
   country     VARCHAR(20),
   language    VARCHAR(20),
   population  INT,
   stats       INT
)
insert into TableB values(1,'India','Hindi',10,2009)
insert into TableB values(2,'India','Hindi',10,2011)
insert into TableB values(3,'India','Hindi',10,2012)

Rewrote the query slightly in different way

select distinct a.id
from (
SELECT a.* 
FROM   TableA a 
WHERE  a.country="India" 
AND    a.language ="Hindi" ) a, TableB   b
WHere ( CASE WHEN a.written=1 THEN
               TRUE
            WHEN ( (a.spoken = 1) AND (a.country=b.country) AND (a.language=b.language)) THEN
                 (case WHEN ((a.population < b.population) AND (a.stats > b.stats)) THEN
                        TRUE
                  WHEN (a.population > b.population) THEN
                       TRUE
                  ELSE
                     FALSE              
                END)
             ELSE
               FALSE
             END)
 got below results
 1,2,4,5
```

This is what I need, now could you please help me in writing it more efficient manner

Comment: 1. There are two tables a and b, for given Country and Language Query a and then for the same given Country and language join on b and if the population of a.population is greater than b.population only then pick the record.

Comment: the tables both a and b have same schema, the data in it has different meaning

Comment: I need to join b only when a.spoken = true, else just return the record from a     with out joining with b.

Comment: figure it out yourself, with population of 11 in rows 4&5 of TableA how on earth can population of 10 in tableB be `>11`?? when you figure out how to clearly prepare a question then I might attempt another answer here is a start (which took me time to prepare!) http://rextester.com/DZK63398

Comment: Hi Used_By_Already Thanks Much! for your time and Help from Yesterday.Yes, I wasted lot of your time by not expressing the problem correctly. Sorry about it

Comment: 1. Row 1 will be picked up by (a.population <b.population AND    a.statsyear > b.statsyear))                                                                                       2. Row 2 will be picked up by (a.population > b.population)                         3. Rows 4 & 5 will be picked up by (a.written = true ) Now this is the main point Table A will be joined to Table B only when spoken=true, otherwise it should return results based on Table A conditions

Comment: Hope I calrified this time. Thanks again for all the help you have given.

Comment: I shall give you a few hours to think it over, it's 14 comments from you so far each one has changed the question dramatically.

Comment: by the way please verify that the sample data at http://rextester.com/DZK63398  is 100% correct. I will wait for your reply to this.

Comment: Yes, the data you have setup is correct

Comment: I updated my post, with working example. Could you please help me in writing this query more efficiently. Again Thanks much for your time Used_BYAlready .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boolean logic equivalent:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.* 
FROM   TableA a 
left join TableB b on a.country=b.country AND a.language=b.language
WHERE  a.country='India' 
AND    a.language ='Hindi'
AND (
        a.written=1
    OR
       (a.spoken = 1 AND a.population < b.population AND a.stats > b.stats)
    OR
       a.population > b.population
    )
;
```

**Result:**

```
+----+---------+----------+--------+---------+------------+-------+
| id | country | language | spoken | written | population | stats |
+----+---------+----------+--------+---------+------------+-------+
|  1 | India   | Hindi    |      1 |       0 |          9 |  2010 |
|  2 | India   | Hindi    |      1 |       0 |         11 |  2011 |
|  4 | India   | Hindi    |      0 |       1 |         10 |  2013 |
|  5 | India   | Hindi    |      1 |       1 |         10 |  2012 |
+----+---------+----------+--------+---------+------------+-------+
```

[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/JWKA28429)

Comment: Very good solution!. I would like to accept the answer and give you a bravo. How can I do that

Comment: I think you figured out the acceptance, if you also wish you may "upvote" also (click the arrow head pointing upwards) but I'm not sure if you need more reputation points to do that or not.

Comment: apart from accepting, its not allowing me for further actions. I wish I would have given you a badge/bravo. Thanks for the Help!

Comment: I want to take it to next step. How can I improve the solution, so that, without using distinct I can get only the matched records(1,2,3,4,5) by adding extra conditions. Because for large data set this solution will not work as there are many duplicates

Comment: You are now asking a new performance related question. In that question you need to include the DDL of your tables and the explain plan of you existing query. Knowing what columns are indexed is vital. Without those things you wont get an answer. include how many rows in both tables too.

Comment: Yeah, solved it by filtering and then join filtered data.